# Table order change when puting the query result into a new table

Tags: sql-server

when I run my query I get the result I'm after, however when I try to input that into a new table (INTO new_table_name) and review it after, the order of the original query is scrambled.

This is my query. Is it because the INTO-statment is before the ORDER BY-statment?

```
SELECT t.TABLE_SCHEMA AS [Parent], 
t.TABLE_NAME AS [Object],
t.COLUMN_NAME AS [Type], 
cd.value AS [Description]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t
INTO new_table_name
INNER JOIN syscolumns c
ON c.name = t.COLUMN_NAME
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties cd
ON cd.major_id = c.id
AND cd.minor_id = c.colid
AND cd.name = 'MS_Description'
ORDER BY t.TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: there's no "original" order in a table, the only way to consistently get rows in order is by using `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see the data in order then use `Order by` while selecting the new table.

Though you used order by while inserting records into table that doesn't mean the records are stored in the data pages in same order or will be retrieved in that order.

Use `Order by` while selecting to see the result in order

```
select * from new_table_name
Order by Object
```

Comment: Thank you fot the quick answer,  didn't think about that.

Comment: Everyone has this misconception ;)